# Does v8 optimize string concatenation inside loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, compiler-optimization, primitive

**TL;DR**: Does v8 optimize string concatenation inside loops, or should I take care of it myself?

---

From one of the episodes of [HTTP 203 podcast](https://youtu.be/S0NQwttnr1I?t=920) (definitely check it out if you don't know about it) I heard about one of the optimizations that are generally handled by the compiler/optimizer: extracting constants out of loops. This made me think about the difference between the following two approaches:

```
let string = "";

getSubstrings().forEach((substring) => {
  string += substring;
});

doSmth(string);
```

```
const chunks = new Array(getSubstringsCount()); // suppose we know array size in advance

getSubstrings().forEach((substring, index) => {
  chunks[index] = substring;
});

const string = chunks.join("");

doSmth(string);
```

<sub>In the first approach, in each iteration we create a new string, that's bigger and bigger in each iteration, and it gets immediately abandoned in the next iteration. In the second approach, we have a fixed number of strings, plus one array object, plus one more `.join()` call.</sub>

I always leaned towards the second approach, but I can see how this might be a silly thing, given that v8 currently is sufficiently advanced from being indistinguishable from magic.

In the case of a very big array (like 10<sup>8</sup> items big), is this something I should worry about? Or v8 already takes care of that for me?